# How to remove option from auto completion select list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to remove the option from the auto completion input drop down select list.

Unable to get the option value until unless i click on input drop down list. Once I click on the input field the options are auto populating, But i dont know how to get the option here.

The input field before click on it:

```js
<div class="field-group">
    <label for="add-reminders-role-picker">Project Role</label>
     <div class="aui-ss" id="add-reminders-role-picker-single-select">
  <input autocomplete="off" class="text aui-ss-field ajs-dirty-warning-exempt" id="add-reminders-role-picker-field">
  <div class="aui-list" id="add-reminders-role-picker-suggestions" tabindex="-1"></div>
  <span class="icon aui-ss-icon noloading drop-menu"><span>More</span></span></div>
 <select class="aui-field-select select aui-ss-select" name="roleName" id="add-reminders-role-picker" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

After click on input field:

```js
<div class="field-group">
    <label for="add-reminders-role-picker">Project Role</label>
 <div class="aui-ss" id="add-reminders-role-picker-single-select" data-query="">
  <input autocomplete="off" class="text aui-ss-field ajs-dirty-warning-exempt" id="add-reminders-role-picker-field">
  <div class="ajs-layer-placeholder">
   <div class="ajs-layer box-shadow" style="width: 248px; position: fixed; left: 153.667px; top: 399.167px; max-height: 171.833px; display: none;">
    <div class="aui-list" id="add-reminders-role-picker-suggestions" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;">
     <div class="aui-list-scroll" tabindex="-1">
      <h5>Project role</h5>
       <ul class="aui-list-section aui-last" id="project-role">
        <li class="aui-list-item aui-list-item-li-administrators active">
         <a class="aui-list-item-link" href="#" title="Administrators">Administrators</a>
        </li>
        <li class="aui-list-item aui-list-item-li-developers">
         <a class="aui-list-item-link" href="#" title="Developers">Developers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="aui-list-item aui-list-item-li-event-watchers">
         <a class="aui-list-item-link" href="#" title="Event Watchers">Event Watchers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="aui-list-item aui-list-item-li-privilege-users">
         <a class="aui-list-item-link" href="#" title="Privilege Users">Privilege Users</a>
        </li>
        <li class="aui-list-item aui-list-item-li-users">
         <a class="aui-list-item-link" href="#" title="Users">Users</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  <span class="icon aui-ss-icon drop-menu noloading"><span>More</span></span></div>

 <select class="aui-field-select select aui-ss-select" name="roleName" id="add-reminders-role-picker" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
  <option value=""></option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Here I want to remove the "Users" option from the 'li' in the second code snippet. Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#aui-list-item-li-users').remove();
```

this code will remove the 'li' with the class = aui-list-item-li-users